# Clone error when passing an object in the route of angular

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, clone

I am trying to pass objects in my angular project instead of separate fields. But i am receiving a "Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned." :(

This is the code:

```
 var errorJsonNav: NavigationExtras = {state:{errorJson:ErrorJsonDTO}};
 this.router.navigate(['error'], errorJsonNav);
```

This is the DTO:

```
export class ErrorJsonDTO {
  excepcionProducida: boolean;
  errorDescripcion: string;
  codigoIncidencia: string;
  correcto: boolean;
  falloSistema:boolean;
  horaActual: string;
  mensajeBase: string;
```

}

And this the data of the example:

[image]

The fields are very simple, some strings and some booleans. Why i have a clone problem? :(

Regards

Comment: You are trying to export a "class" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the guide of ritesh i make the solution.

The component sender must code this:

```
var errorJsonNav: NavigationExtras = {state:{errorJson:errorJson}};
this.router.navigate(['error'], errorJsonNav);
```

So the error, in the first line, was in the state part. State must have a key-value format. Isnt necesary to indicate the type of the object i am sending.

In the component receiver is good the original code:

```
var navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
var state = navigation?.extras.state as {errorJson:ErrorJsonDTO};
this.errorJson = state.errorJson;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a valid value to state:

```
{state:{errorJson:ErrorJsonDTO}};
```

`ErrorJsonDTO` is a type and you need to pass a value of type `ErrorJsonDTO`

Try this if errorJson is a valid value of type `ErrorJsonDTO`

```
 this.router.navigate(['error'], state: { errorJson });
```

Comment: Yep, its works, i write the solution. The last line that you write confused me, because you put the data i want to send, not the navigationextras. Thanks!

Comment: yes the last line is a shorthand, so {name: name} is same as {name} in es6. Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped :). Cheers.

Comment: Check this link to further understand that: https://ui.dev/shorthand-properties/#:~:text=With%20Shorthand%20Properties%2C%20whenever%20you,can%20omit%20the%20property%20name.